# Where should I ask about sodium bicarbonate as a cleaning agent?

Tags: discussion, food-safety

I can't find an authoritative answer to the question @rumtscho asked me [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/33347/641) about the concentration of sodium bicarbonate.

I've seen just about any combination you can think of:

- With just enough water to form a paste.
- With water and vinegar.
- with lots of water.
- 5% dilution in water.
- 0.5% dilution in water.

Most 'recipes' are not very exact. I've also read that it can be harmful, so the issue is not without interest. Especially as I've been cleaning my fridge with the 5% dilution.

Others, on the Internet, claim that it's a harmless substance and recommend it against stomach pains.

Should I just dump this question on the main site, or will it get closed?

Comment: Just ask. If it gets closed, it's not the end of the world, and it'll inform *this* discussion. Much more productive to discuss a specific question.

Comment: @Shog9, done http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34142/at-what-concentration-is-sodium-bicarbonate-a-sanitizing-solution